# Create a custom RestControllerAnotation to execute a requestMapping

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, annotations, spring-restcontroller

Good afternoon,

I have a restController and I want to create an annotation that allows or not to execute a method based on an a custom header value.
If custom header tag equals something then the method must execute, if the custom header dont match, the method musth not execute
I have followed several articles but I have not been able.

I attached the code I created:

**Annotation Code:**

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ApiVersion {
    int[] value();
}
```

**ApiVersionRequestMappingHandlerMapping**

```
    public class ApiVersionRequestMappingHandlerMapping extends RequestMappingHandlerMapping {

    private final String prefix;

    public ApiVersionRequestMappingHandlerMapping(String prefix) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    @Override
    protected RequestMappingInfo getMappingForMethod(Method method, Class<?> handlerType) {
        RequestMappingInfo info = super.getMappingForMethod(method, handlerType);
        if(info == null) return null;

        ApiVersion methodAnnotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(method, ApiVersion.class);
        if(methodAnnotation != null) {
            RequestCondition<?> methodCondition = getCustomMethodCondition(method);
            // Concatenate our ApiVersion with the usual request mapping
            info = createApiVersionInfo(methodAnnotation, methodCondition).combine(info);
        } else {
            ApiVersion typeAnnotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(handlerType, ApiVersion.class);
            if(typeAnnotation != null) {
                RequestCondition<?> typeCondition = getCustomTypeCondition(handlerType);
                // Concatenate our ApiVersion with the usual request mapping
                info = createApiVersionInfo(typeAnnotation, typeCondition).combine(info);
            }
        }

        return info;
    }

    private RequestMappingInfo createApiVersionInfo(ApiVersion annotation, RequestCondition<?> customCondition) {
        int[] values = annotation.value();
        String[] patterns = new String[values.length];
        for(int i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
            // Build the URL prefix
            patterns[i] = prefix+values[i];
        }

        return new RequestMappingInfo(
                new PatternsRequestCondition(patterns, getUrlPathHelper(), getPathMatcher(), useSuffixPatternMatch(), useTrailingSlashMatch(), getFileExtensions()),
                new RequestMethodsRequestCondition(),
                new ParamsRequestCondition(),
                new HeadersRequestCondition(),
                new ConsumesRequestCondition(),
                new ProducesRequestCondition(),
                customCondition);
    }

}
```

**Rest Controller**

```
    @RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api/example")
public class ExampleController {

    private final UserService userService;

   @ApiVersion (1)
    @GetMapping("/myMethod")
   public String myMethod(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserAuthenticatedDetails userAuthenticated) {

      return userAuthenticated.getUsername();
    }
}
```

**ApiConfig** 
     package xx.package.sample;

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@ComponentScan("xx.package")
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EntityScan("xx.package.domain.entity")
@EnableJpaRepositories("xx.package.domain.repository")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ApiConfig {
 }
```

I know I'm missing something but I can't see what.

Regards, and thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

You could use `@GetMapping(path = "/myMethod", headers = "My-Header=myValue")`.

> a sequence of "My-Header=myValue" style expressions, with a request
>   only mapped if each such header is found to have the given value

see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html#headers--

Comment: Good Morning,
I already knew that solution and it suits me for the objective.
I preferred to know how to create an annotation that would do that to know how it is done.

Comment: Well, if it doesn't bother you I'll let the answers for the beginners which might be tempted to implement their annotation for solving this topic while spring support already exists. But if it is not welcomed I'll just delete it.